# ssh sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \1 on `s'

Tags: ssh, sed

I would like to update code between square brackets with double quotes.

```
$td[blabla]="x";
```

to

```
$td["blabla"]="x";
```

In read is ok with -r

```
sed -r -e 's/\[([_a-z1-9]*)]/["\1"]/g' "test.php"
```

But to write is down

```
sed -i -e 's/\[([_a-z1-9]*)]/["\1"]/g' "test.php"
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

It seems that the expression is not understood, but why?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-r` similar to `-E` enables `ERE` giving you access to extended functionality within your script. The removal of it reverts back to `BRE`

To fix your second code, you can either escape the parenthesis or readd the `-r` option to re-enable extended functionality.

```
$ sed -ri.bak 's/\[([_a-z1-9]*)]/["\1"]/g' test.php
```

You can also try this `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak 's/\[([^]]*)/["\1"/' test.php
$ cat test.php
$td["blabla"]="x";
```

The `-i.bak` will also create a backup of your file with .bak extension